Service Fabric SDK on Windows 2019 Microsoft Hosted not found by ServiceFabricDeploy@1 task
Using a Microsoft Hosted Windows 2019 agent (image). The specification (see documentation) states that the Service Fabric SDK is installed. However, the Service Fabric Deploy task is not able to find the Fabric SDK (which is a dependency). Looking at the source (see code) behind the task the Fabric SDK is expected to be located at:
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric SDK
Using a simple PowerShell task and the Test-Path directive (i.e. Test-Path -Path “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric SDK”) the directory is not on the image.
Another thing is that the 9.1 SDK is not same as our Azure Fabric resource at 10.1 (here is the documentation on available Fabric SDK versions).
Downloading and trying to install the SDK is not an option because the CURRENT USER has no access to C:\Program Files.
Suggestions? On my local machine the Fabric key is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric SDK and the name value pairs point the Fabric SDK installation path to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric. Likely the path on the image (i.e. C:\Program Files) and I would guess CURRENT USER can not add a registry key that points to anything under C:\Program files.
